# Local Data Store ParseQuery orderByDescending with createdAt doesn't work

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to get last 5 entries in my local table with following query:

```
List<ParseObject> results = new ArrayList();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Chat"+params[0]);
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.setLimit(5);
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
try {
    results = query.find();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above query still gives me 5 items created first even though I add orderByDescending constraint. I only want last 5 items that I created locally.

Comment: Why do you have `query.fromLocalDatastore();`

Comment: Because I never save this on cloud, only locally on phone.

Comment: Have you tried `orderByAscending`?

Comment: Yes, no chance. Also I believe that I should order by descending, am I wrong?

Comment: Latest to earliest is descending so you're right. I was curious if you'd get different data by changing the `orderBy`.

Comment: I am attempting to write an iOS app without using core data and solely relying on parse local datastore. I thought it would be simpler because there is only a small amount of data in a couple of small classes that needs to be stored. However, some of the functionality for running queries is lacking. This happens to be one of them for iOS too. It seems like it should be very basic.

Comment: @MuratAyan Did you ever work out a solution to this?

Comment: @LandLPartners Sorry no chance.